# localhost no longer working on other devices on network with new router

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have recently installed a new router within my home (the `Asus RT-AC88U`).

Originally, I used to only have my ISP's general modem-router. However, it became slow when I am trying to access it from another room in the house, so I have connected a new router to it.

Initially, the `Asus RT-AC88U` worked perfectly, however, when it comes to trying to access my computer's localhost (i.e: `192.168.1.21`) an another device connected to the **same** network, I would be greeted by a long wait, and finally the error:

> Could not open the page because the server stopped responding.

or

> http://192.168.1.21 is unreachable.

My localhost used to work on the old modem-router, but now it no longer wants to work on the new one. I'm a bit confused, so any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Try connecting two devices by ethernet cable to the new ASUS router, does your error persist?

Comment: Have you your new ASUS behind the original modem/router?  And how is this configured?  Bridge mode?

Comment: @Progrock I'll have a look now :)

Comment: @Progrock sorry, I don't understand your question :/

Comment: Well it seems like local area network is being fire walled by your new router some routers tend not to block the internal network but some do you might have to look at the firmware of the router and see what's blocking your LAN access. Look under firewall or NAT but from the symptoms it seems like the firewall is blocking the access.

Comment: A little diagram/schematic of your network topology may help here.

Comment: @Sand do you know what I should be looking for within my firewall settings to disable / alter?